# hangfire dashboard on several web servers

Tags: hangfire

We have two servers and would like to deploy a hangfire dashboard on both so we can take down one of the machines for maintenance if/as needed. They will both access shared tables in the same database. They will not be load balanced, but they both should be accessible from seperate internal Urls at the same time.

Are there any problems with deploying the dashboard on multiple IIS servers? Should each instance have a BackgroundJobServer running or will this cause issues?

I had a related issue I have moved onto the hangfire forums https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/scheduled-job-starts-processing-twice/3076

Comment: So is your question about load balancing just hangfire, or just the dashboard, or both?

Comment: @tom-redfern we're actually not going to be loadbalancing hangfire, its an intended as an internal dashboard, but we would like to have it exposed on both servers? its really about deploying the dashboard in two places, and if starting a background job server on both is the correct decision

Comment: There is no problem with having the dashboard on two different servers. The dashboard does not affect job processing. It's simply an interface. Was that your entire question?

Comment: @mason, when the application starts, it creates an instance of the BackgroundJob Server - am I allowed to create one in each application?

Comment: I believe I just answered that in the previous comment. Yes, the dashboard is independent. You could run the dashboard standalone, or you can run it in the same project. You could have 5 dashboards and one background server if you really wanted. It is simply an interface.

Comment: @mason I guess the great thing about hangfire is that it runs application code / class methods on schedules. do I need to do anything to ensure the code methods are not executed in both web applications?

Comment: No. Are you sure this job got executed twice? What does job 19 look like in the Hangfire Dashboard? If it errored the first time, it might enter the processing state twice. Which is why looking at the database tables that Hangfire generates can be misleading and you shouldn't assume anything about how they work.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not show any retries - it did not error the first time. I want to make sure - can we have more than one background server? does background server = instance of BackgroundJobServer class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138043/discussion-between-user1778606-and-mason).

Comment: There's nothing to chat about. If Hangfire is running jobs twice, then file [an issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues) with them.

Comment: done, thanks for your help